# Calling main Activity to start when a Share Intent is called

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent, android-activity

I was not sure how to search for this thing, so ended up posting the question.

I have an app, that requires Authentication for using it. I added a Share Intent to it, so that other apps could be able to Share using my app.

The main activity is StarterActivity that calls LoginActivity. But, my share activity is ShareActivity which is called when people use share via my app.

My question is, currently when I select "Share" it directly takes me to the Share Activity, without authentication.

How do I make the behavior such that when a user selects my app from "Share" it first asks them to Login and on successful login, take them to Share Activity, along with the data that they passed while using the Share Intent.

I hope the question was understandable.

Please help.

Regards.

Comment: in your share activity(onCreate) check first user is login or not.. if not then redirect him in to main activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, you might want to start your application this way, every time the application launch, it goes to StarterActivity, this will check whether you're logged in or not, if yes, it starts ShareActivity, if not, it starts LoginActivity.

In this case, when user selects "share", you still launch StarterActivity, passing in share details with an extra using Intent.putExtra() function, which you will be passing from Starter to Login, lastly to Share, is this what you would prefer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like this is what I was trying to do. One quick question, I am receiving the data from a 3rd party file manager or gallery, so do I directly send them using the putExtra to login activity, even if it is not needed there. Or do I process it in some other form before sending?

Comment: I would choose to putExtra into login activity, because login activity will need this extra to open up share activity. I guess you need to pass the extra from login activity to share activity?